# How to override Sylius variation form options in product show?

Tags: symfony, e-commerce, symfony4, sylius

I have a Sylius installation where I added a configurable product with multiple variation.

In shop product page, how to make the choice of product option appear as a radio button instead of a dropdown(select) ?

Using Sylius v1.7.4
[image]

Comment: Can you show the code for that form?

Comment: @JulienB.
The form in generated by Sylius Core based on options defined for the product in the administration. Here is a [screenshot](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/6bJ7ZwZN9yqLWLl1O9fUyyk_hAGhgltPMJz04vSuxjf6YfGs03VElZhBDCEXtFw3e2y_19z06JqochZ4O5DE=w1280-h545-rw) of the form in Symfony profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend the Form as described here: [Customizing Forms](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/customization/form.html)

Then you can remove the relevant fiels and add the same one just changing the expanded option to 'true' so that it renders radio buttons instead, see: [Symfony ChoiceType documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#expanded)